# Moment JS how to set is between and equal between 2 dates?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I would like to check if given date is between 2 dates with hours of course. So if we check if 13:00 is between 13:00 and 15:00 I would like to get true.

I have this code:

```
 let timeSlotStartTime = moment.utc(timeSlot.startTime);
    let startDayTime =  moment.utc(timeSlotStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T" + moment.utc(condition.parameters.timeFrom).format('HH:mm:00'));
    let endDayTime =  moment.utc(timeSlotStartTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "T" + moment.utc(condition.parameters.timeTo).format('HH:mm:59'));
    return timeSlotStartTime.isBetween(startDayTime, endDayTime);
```

So I am checking if it is between but it works weird.

If I set hours of startDayTime = 14:59 and endDayTime = 17:00
and timeSlotStartTime is 14:15 it stills gives me true.(this is the bigger problem)

and if timeSlotStartTime = 17:00 gives me false (which I want to give me true)

Is there any possibility I can check between and equal within 2 moments?

thanks

Comment: [documentation here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/) indicates that you can pass an argument to `isBetween` that allows it to include the ends

Comment: double check the strings you're forming, if `isBetween` is giving unexpected results then there is probably an issue with your dates

Comment: .isBetween() compares by milliseconds by default but maybe if you put 'minute' as a 3rd argument it will return false in your first example instead of true.

Comment: I ran timeSlotStartTime.isBetween(startDayTime, endDayTime) with the times you provided and received false. I think @RobbieMilejczak is correct. Its probably a issue with your dates

Comment: OP, it would be nice if your example code filled out the timeSlot object for us so if someone is trying to test a solution, they don't have to guess what values you put in there.

Comment: You need to pass in 3rd and 4th parameter to `isBetween` timeSlotStartTime.isBetween(startDayTime, endDayTime, 'minutes', '[]');

Answer (score 29, accepted):

https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/

You can use the 4th argument to include edges

```
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '[)'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '(]'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', null, '[]'); //true
```

Where square brackets means 'include this end' and parentheses means 'exclude this end'

Comment: "If I set hours of startDayTime = 14:59 and endDayTime = 17:00 and timeSlotStartTime is 14:15 it stills gives me true.(this is the bigger problem)" this only answers a small part of OP's question

Answer (score 7):

[`isBetween`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/) takes a third parameter (minutes, hours,days etc) and fourth parameter `[]` to include inclusivity

You should pass the third parameter as **'minutes'** since you are comparing minutes

```
var timeSlotStartTime  = moment({ hour:14, minute:15 });
var startDayTime  = moment({ hour:14, minute:59 });
var endDayTime   = moment({ hour:17, minute:00 });


var result = timeSlotStartTime.isBetween(startDayTime, endDayTime, 'minutes', '[]');

console.log(result); // false
```

Also [`isBetween`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/) match is exclusive.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-01-01', '2012-01-01', 'year'); // false as it is exclusive
```

Version 2.13.0 introduces inclusivity. A `[` indicates inclusion of a value. A `(` indicates exclusion. If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed.

```
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', null, '[)'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', null, '(]'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', null, '[]'); //true
```

Comment: "If I set hours of startDayTime = 14:59 and endDayTime = 17:00 and timeSlotStartTime is 14:15 it stills gives me true.(this is the bigger problem)" this only answers a small part of OP's question