# Why Moment isBetween not working? result is false

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why Moment isBetween not working? `moment(obj.date).isBetween` returned false.

```
let dates = [
    {date:'11/26/2020'},
    {date:'11/26/2020'},
    {date:'11/27/2020'},
  ];

let filtered_data = _.filter(dates, (obj)=>{
  console.log(moment(moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')).isBetween('2020-11-25', '2020-11-26'));
  console.log(moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  return moment(obj.date).isBetween('2020-11-25', '2020-11-25');
}); 

console.log(filtered_data);
```

Comment: isBetween on  '2020-11-25', '2020-11-25' range maybe not defined, both of them is the same day.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260985/moment-js-how-to-set-is-between-and-equal-between-2-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let filtered_data = _.filter((obj: any) => {
  console.log(moment(moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')).isBetween('2020-11-25', '2020-11-26', undefined, '[]'));
  console.log(moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  return moment(moment(obj.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')).isBetween('2020-11-25', '2020-11-26', undefined, '[]');
});
```

Here are other examples:

```
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', undefined, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-12-30', undefined, '[)'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', undefined, '()'); //false
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-01-01', '2016-10-30', undefined, '(]'); //true
moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', undefined, '[]'); //true
```

Refer to this link:

[Moment JS how to set is between and equal between 2 dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260985/moment-js-how-to-set-is-between-and-equal-between-2-dates)

Comment: Yes, I forgot that there are four parameters on the isBetween function. That's what I'am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Get your date from string `MM-DD-YYYY` in this way

```
moment(obj.date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

```js
var data = [
    {date:'11/26/2020'},
    {date:'11/27/2020'},
    {date:'11/28/2020'}
  ];

let filtered_data = data.filter(obj => {
  let dateToCompare = moment(obj.date, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
  return dateToCompare.isBetween('2020-11-25', '2020-11-28');
}); 

console.log(filtered_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Read more about `.isBetween()` here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/06-is-between/)

Comment: @Mike Harvey Ambait Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: ahh I was just missing 2 prameters in the isBetween function. 3rd parameter is required for the granularity of the filter and the fourth one is for the inclusivity of which data.

Answer (score 0):

Moment JS **isBetween** check between todays only.

Ex :-

```
dates = [{date:'11/26/2020'},{date:'11/26/2020'},{date:'11/27/2020'}];
let filtered_data = dates.filter((obj)=>moment(obj.date).isBetween('2020-11-25',
'2020-11-27'));
```

Output :-

> [{"date":"11/26/2020"},{"date":"11/26/2020"}]

Check this momentjs playground example :-

https://jsfiddle.net/n6ecmbxv/2/